# Using MEF with plugins that require "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" in app.config

Tags: .net, vb.net, mef, legacy

I'm using MEF to load plugins to my host application. The host and the plugins are all .Net 4.0 Client Profile. However, some of these plugins reference a library System.Data.SQLite.dll which requires an App.config file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

In the past I would plop the [libname].dll.config file in the same directory as [libname].dll and it would work. However, my plugin libraries are in a different folder and copying the application config files and the System.Data.SQLite.dll to that folder doesn't work. My solution compiles properly but I get the following exception at run time when the plugins are attempting to instantiate a database:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I don't think it matters but it occurs on this line (EventDbWriter is belongs to database wrapper class):

```
EventDbWriter = EventDbWriter.CreateWriter(filename, systemId, applicationId, applicationStatus, projectPath)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: some of the notable fuslogvw lines are as follows:

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable C:\...\VS2010\DL_PEM\branches\DL_PEM\DL_PEM\bin\Debug\DL_PEM.vshost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = DemoModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=x86
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/...\VS2010/DL_PEM/branches/DL_PEM/DL_PEM/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = DL_PEM.vshost.exe
Calling assembly : System.ComponentModel.Composition, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\...\VS2010\DL_PEM\branches\DL_PEM\DL_PEM\bin\Debug\DL_PEM.vshost.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../VS2010/DL_PEM/branches/DL_PEM/DL_PEM/bin/Debug/DemoModule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../VS2010/DL_PEM/branches/DL_PEM/DL_PEM/bin/Debug/DemoModule/DemoModule.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../VS2010/DL_PEM/branches/DL_PEM/DL_PEM/bin/Debug/DemoModule.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/.../VS2010/DL_PEM/branches/DL_PEM/DL_PEM/bin/Debug/DemoModule/DemoModule.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Another assembly binding error was detected, part of the log is as follows:

```
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\IntelliTrace\11.0.0\IntelliTrace.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
```

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to find out where it looked.

Comment: Thank you . I obtained some results and posted them in my post. I still don't know what's wrong though. It seems that the plugins are able to use reference libraries in the host application's directory but not the legacy ones.

Comment: I should add that DL_PEM is the host application and DemoModule.dll is the plugin in a different folder (DL_PEM\Plugins\DemoModule.dll). It seems as though an attempt to download is looking in the plugin project's debug folder.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that almost did it. However, to get it working I had to place the legacy dll in the plugin directory and use the <probing> element in the app.config file of the host executable. Something like:

Comment: [host directory] \ [windows user account name]\ModulePlugins. I have two concerns: the user name will obviously be changed per account and I would rather avoid copying over dlls to the plugin folder. The infrastructure is intended for other developers to simply drop in their dll and test with my host app... avoiding any app.config files per plugin would also be ideal. Also, I keep getting the second binding error, do you think this is related to any of my issues? Thanks!